# catkin commands not working

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros and catkin but when I echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

```
Inspiron-5559:~/catkin_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

i don't get the src folder of catkin workspace along with it.Also catkin config command gives the following error.

```
Inspiron-5559:~/catkin_ws$ catkin config
catkin: command not found
```

**How do I resolve the issue?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278620/catkin-commands-not-working/) by [nrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33066/nrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `catkin` command line tool is part of the `python-catkin-tools` Ubuntu/Debian package, which must be installed separately from the normal installation instructions of ROS. You can install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools
```

After that it will work even if you don't source the `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` file first.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33066/nrb/) on 2018-01-03**:
Thank you...this helped